# Dynamicly add a Button that is linked to an action

Tags: stimulusjs

On connect, I want to add some markup that is connected to an action within the same controller.  Is this possible?  How is it done?

This is what I am trying so far in my tricksmods controller:

```
addEmbedButton() {
    const buttonHTML = '<button type="button" class="trix-button" data-trix-attribute="embed"   data-action="click->tricksmods#showembed" title="Embed" tabindex="-1">Embed</button>'
    this.buttonGroupBlockTools.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", buttonHTML)
  }

showembed(){
  console.log('showembed')
}
```

The markup is added, but the showembed action is not fired on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this out.  I needed to use the toolbarElement of the trix editor to get at my button and dialog.

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import Trix from 'trix'
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"

export default class extends Controller {
  static get targets() {
      return [ "field" ]
  }

  connect() {
    this.addEmbedButton()
    this.addEmbedDialog()
    this.eventListenerForEmbedButton()
    this.eventListenerForAddEmbedButton()
  }

  addEmbedButton() {
    const buttonHTML = '<button  type="button" class="trix-button tricks-embed"  data-trix-attribute="embed" data-trix-action="embed"   data-action="click->tricks#showembed" title="Embed" tabindex="-1">Embed</button>'
    this.buttonGroupBlockTools.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", buttonHTML)
  }

  addEmbedDialog() {
    const dialogHTML = `<div class="trix-dialog trix-dialog--link" data-trix-dialog="embed" data-trix-dialog-attribute="embed" data-tricks-target="embeddialog">
                          <div class="trix-dialog__link-fields">
                            <input type="text" name="embed" class="trix-input trix-input--dialog" placeholder="Paste your URL" aria-label="embed code" required="" data-trix-input="" disabled="disabled">
                            <div class="trix-button-group">
                              <input type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--dialog" data-trix-custom="add-embed" value="Add">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>`
    this.dialogsElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", dialogHTML)
  }

  showembed(e){
    console.log('showembed')
    const dialog = this.toolbarElement.querySelector('[data-trix-dialog="embed"]')
    const embedInput = this.dialogsElement.querySelector('[name="embed"]')
    if (event.target.classList.contains("trix-active")) {
      event.target.classList.remove("trix-active");
      dialog.classList.remove("trix-active");
      delete dialog.dataset.trixActive;
      embedInput.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
      event.target.classList.add("trix-active");
      dialog.classList.add("trix-active");
      dialog.dataset.trixActive = "";
      embedInput.removeAttribute("disabled");
      embedInput.focus();
    }
  }

  eventListenerForEmbedButton() {
    this.toolbarElement.querySelector('[data-trix-action="embed"]').addEventListener("click", e => {
      this.showembed(e)
    })
  }

  eventListenerForAddEmbedButton() {
    this.dialogsElement.querySelector('[data-trix-custom="add-embed"]').addEventListener("click", event => {
      console.log('embeddy')
      const content = this.dialogsElement.querySelector("[name='embed']").value
      if (content) {
        let _this = this
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("content", content)
        Rails.ajax({
          type: 'PATCH',
          url: '/admin/embed.json',
          data: formData,
          success: ({content, sgid}) => {
            const attachment = new Trix.Attachment({content, sgid})
            _this.element.editor.insertAttachment(attachment)
            _this.element.editor.insertLineBreak()
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }

  //////////////// UTILS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  get buttonGroupBlockTools() {
   return this.toolbarElement.querySelector("[data-trix-button-group=block-tools]")
 }

 get buttonGroupTextTools() {
   return this.toolbarElement.querySelector("[data-trix-button-group=text-tools]")
 }

 get buttonGroupFileTools(){
   return this.toolbarElement.querySelector("[data-trix-button-group=file-tools]")
 }

 get dialogsElement() {
   return this.toolbarElement.querySelector("[data-trix-dialogs]")
 }

 get toolbarElement() {
    return this.element.toolbarElement
  }
}
```